# Error compiling https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.7

I copied the code from this tutorial into a pycharm project and setup my venv with tensorflow and matplotlib. When I try to compile the code I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
    File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
    File "C:/Users/sirch/PycharmProjects/Cats_vs_Dogs/venv/Test_NN.py", line 52, in <module>
sample_training_images, _ = next(train_data_gen)
    File "C:\Users\sirch\PycharmProjects\Cats_vs_Dogs\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 104, in __next__
return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\sirch\PycharmProjects\Cats_vs_Dogs\venv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 116, in next
```

From the error messages I assume the problem is with the next line of the code:

```
    train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our training data
    validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255) # Generator for our validation data
    train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                       directory=train_dir,
                                                       shuffle=True,
                                                       target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                       class_mode='binary')
    val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                          directory=validation_dir,
                                                          target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                          class_mode='binary')
    sample_training_images, _ = next(train_data_gen)
```

Any idea what this error really is or why it is happening?

Comment: Two things: Python does not have a compilation step, and your traceback is incomplete, it does not actually have the error message.

Comment: CPython compiles Python to CPython bytecode, but nonetheless this is an error at runtime, not compile-time.

Comment: These are all the error lines that I got from my cmd which is part of why I've been struggling to debug it.